# PowerShell nested foreach with data used from both?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I literally have been working on what seemed to be an easy task for over a week. What I am trying to do is have two variables that contain data and use them as stuff to loop through for each. The amount in each variable will vary. One thing that is constant is that for every entry in $one, I want to use $two to build a command and run it. If it returns data, I will redirect/append it to a text file.

For Example:

```
$one = get-content C:\one.txt
$two =  get-content C:\two.txt

$one
jon
bob
ed
don

$two
phila
dallas
atlanta
tennessee
alabama
kentucky
```

Desired output:

```
jon phila
jon dallas
jon atlanta
jon tennessee
jon alabama
jon kentucky
bob phila
bob dallas
```

and so on…

Results have been similar to this:

the results are basically like this:

```
jon phila
jon phila
jon phila
jon phila
jon phila
jon dallas
jon dallas
```

What I have so far:

```
foreach ($user in $one)
{
    foreach ($area in $two)
    {
        if (Test-Path $user$area)
        {
            echo $user $area >> output.txt
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Why test-path $one $two? That makes no sense.

Comment: I just adjusted it to code above. I meant to use the variable for the forloop.

Comment: I adjusted the original post to show the current output as well.... sorry

Comment: I was using test-path to see if something is there and then if so, write to the text file

Comment: `Test-Path` asserts whether an item exists at a given path. If you simply want to check that `$user` and `$area` are not empty, do `if($user -and $area){}`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd code what you're doing if both `$one` and `$two` are relatively small (< 1,000 items) but I still don't understand what the problem you're having is:

```
$one = 'jon','bob','ed','don';
$two = 'phila','dallas','atlanta','tennessee','alabama','kentucky';
$result = @();

foreach ($user in $one)
{
    foreach ($area in $two)
    {
        $userarea = "$user $area";
        if (Test-Path $userarea) 
        {
            $result += $userarea;
        }
    }
}

Add-Content -Path .\output.txt -Value $result -Encoding UTF8;
```